# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "("

Tags: c#, sql, строки, postgresql

Ребят вроде написал всё правильно, посмотрев официальную статью, не пойму почему здесь синтаксическая ошибка: "("

```
String SQLString = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (" +
                   $"SQLID integer(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                   $"PlayerName varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' '," +
                   $"Cash integer(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
                   $"Level integer(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
                   $"Age integer(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
                   $"Health integer(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
                   $"PRIMARY KEY (SQLID));";
```

Comment: Я не спец в Postgre, но вот это разве корректно? `integer(11)`

Comment: @tym32167 вроде бы да, хотя везде пишут без значения (11), попробовал убрать, ошибка стала на AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: А вы откуда взяли этот `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Он разве так в postgre делается?

Comment: вот корректный код для создания таблицы https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fa6dcbdf3481c14373c3b3db6e7687ea или можно ```Primary Key``` сразу переместить в объявление типа https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=622c41462d763eee3530793179ca5247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

иправьте  на

```
String SQLString = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (" +
                   $"SQLID serial NOT NULL," +
                   $"PlayerName varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' '," +
                   $"Cash integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
                   $"Level integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
                   $"Age integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
                   $"Health integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
                   $"PRIMARY KEY (SQLID));";
```

Comment: Спасибо, также спасибо за ответ от @Novitskiy Denis, да заработало, работал до этого на mysqli, не знал, что id строки здесь немного иначе, хотя об этом нигде не нашёл.

Comment: @ZerooneX пометить не забудьте если помогло